# What is the difference between HTTP and URLs?

Tags: url, http

What is the difference between HTTP and a URL as used for a website?   How is that related to the layers of HTTP?

Comment: They're completely dufferent things. Used for dufferent purposes. HTTP is a *transfer protocol*, URL is a *resource locator*.

Answer (score 2):

A URL is an address used to locate documents.   Examples of URLs are:

- `http://example.com/mypage.html`
- `ftp://example.com/download.zip`
- `mailto:user@example.com`
- `file:///home/user/file.txt`
- `tel:1-888-555-5555`
- `http://example.com/resource?foo=bar#fragment`

HTTP is the protocol used to fetch some URLs (the ones that start with `http://`) from servers.   A simple HTTP request works like this:

- Parse the server name out of the URL (`example.com`)
- Look up the IP address for that server (`93.184.216.34`)
- Open a socket to that server and write an HTTP request (ending with two new lines):

  ```
  GET /resource?foo=bar HTTP/1.1
  Host: example.com
  ```
- Wait for the response from the server:

  ```
  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  Accept-Ranges: bytes
  Cache-Control: max-age=604800
  Content-Type: text/html
  Date: Tue, 24 Mar 2015 11:00:51 GMT
  Etag: "359670651"
  Expires: Tue, 31 Mar 2015 11:00:51 GMT
  Last-Modified: Fri, 09 Aug 2013 23:54:35 GMT
  Server: ECS (ewr/15BD)
  X-Cache: HIT
  x-ec-custom-error: 1
  Content-Length: 1270

  <!doctype html>
  <html>
  <head>
  ...
  ```

As you can see, a URL is an address and HTTP is a method of talking to a server.

I'm not sure what the HTTP layers you are referring to are.